# Firestore document to Flutter Problem : Exception( type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>')

Tags: flutter, dart, model, provider

Can't get my head around this problem. 
I set the following document to firestore. 
And i need to convert 'attendance' field to a List.

```
 Map<String, dynamic> data = {
  "name": "memberName",
  "attendance": {
    "0": {"morning": false, "noon": true, "night": true},
    "1": {"morning": false, "noon": true, "night": true}
  },
  "deposits": {
    "0": {"date": "date", "amount": 100},
    "1": {"date": "date", "amount": 100}
  }
};
```

Using StreamProvider . Stream has no problem.
using toList()

Documents are fetched. But models are failing. Getting a Exception : [type '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'Map']
Model Classes:

```
class Member {
  String id;
  String name;
  List<Attendance> attendances;
  List<Deposit> deposits;

  Member({this.id, this.name, this.attendances, this.deposits});

  Member.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    Map<String, dynamic> json = doc.data;
    id = doc.documentID;
    name = json['name'];
    if (json['attendance'] != null) {
      Map<String, dynamic> atdmap = json['attendance'];
      attendances = new List<Attendance>();
      atdmap.forEach((k, v) {
        attendances.add(new Attendance.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['deposits'] != null) {
      Map<String, dynamic> dmap = json['deposits'];
      deposits = new List<Deposit>();
      dmap.forEach((k, v) {
        deposits.add(new Deposit.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
}

class Attendance {
  bool morning;
  bool noon;
  bool night;

  Attendance({this.morning, this.noon, this.night});

  Attendance.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    morning = json['morning'];
    noon = json['noon'];
    night = json['night'];
  }
}

class Deposit {
  String date;
  int amount;

  Deposit({this.date, this.amount});

  Deposit.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    date = json['date'];
    amount = json['amount'];
  }
}
```

Where is it getting wrong. need a little help.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try an explicit cast

```
Map<String, dynamic> json = doc.data as Map<String, dynamic>;
```